# Unable to query foreign table using supabase-js

Tags: postgresql, next.js, supabase

I'm trying to use the supabase-js package (with next js) to query data in my supabase postgres DB. I have set up 2 tables. One (users) with a foreign key referencing another (organisations). I've tried querying the data in the following ways:

```
const { data, error } = await supabase.from('users').select(`
  *,
  organisations (
    *
  )
`);

// or

const { data, error } = await supabase.from('users').select('*, organisations(*)');
```

The `supabase` object above is created using `createServerComponentClient` from `@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs`.

But I always get null back for `data.organisations` and for `error`. The rest of the user data is there.

Also, if I query the data directly using an SQL join (`... JOIN organisations ON users.organisation_id = organisations.id`) I am able to fetch the organisation, so I know that the foreign key reference is working in the database. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
"next": "13.4.19",
"@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.37.0",
"@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs": "^0.8.1"
```

Comment: Next.js is a server-side rendering (SSR) framework, so this means that you can't just use the normal `@supabase/supabase-js` with it in order to get the fullness of the framework. You need to use the `@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs`, going through the getting started here will get you up to speed with the auth-helpers and nextjs https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-nextjs

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the reply! I am using the `auth-helpers-nextjs`  package, but that in turn is using the `supabase-js` package. I should have made that more clear. I'm using `createServerComponentClient` from `@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs` (version: ^0.8.1) to create the client that I am using the code in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

In the end the issue was not related to @supabase/supabase-js or @supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs, but the row-level-security (RLS) settings on the table in the database.

When creating a new table via the Studio RLS is set to true by default. If you don't then apply any RLS rules it is not possible to access the data. When I added a rule to allow anyone to read that table and the query worked.

Comment: omg! ty. i wish i had found your post faster. it would have saved me 4 hours of  "shouting in disbelieve at he docs"